# Erro .top no jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#j_menu a").click(function(e) {
  var goto = $("#"+$(this).attr('href').replace('#','')+"");
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: goto.offset().top
    }, 'slow');
});
```

Ele acusa um erro dizendo que não consegue ler ".top" mas em um outro site que estou construindo ele reconheceu.

Comment: Adicionei uma condição para verificar se o elemento realmente existe. `if (goto.length) { $("html,body").animate(...) }`

Comment: O id gerado por `"#"+$(this).attr('href').replace('#','')+""` existe na página ? Faça `console.log(goto);` exatamente a seguir a definição da variável `goto` para ver qual o valor que está a construir.

Answer (score 0):

O recurso `.offset().top` é chamada do jquery, então você deve colocar a varivel dentro de `$()` ficando assim `$(goto).offset().top`. Para pegar posição do elemento somente com javascript tem [essa questão aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/192610/como-pegar-a-posi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-x-e-y-de-um-elemento-relativo-%C3%A0-tela)