# Busca em elemento vivo no mobile

Tags: java, mobile, selenium-webdriver, automatização, testes-automatizados

Estou fazendo automação de teste na empresa onde trabalho, usando Java/Selenium e estou enfrentando um problema ao realizar automação no app, pois a estrutura que usam aqui para desenvolvimento é viva, então sempre muda o id,xpath ou o que for, ai queria saber se tem alguma lib que faz busca de algum elemento vivo ou algo do tipo.

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a que melhor por causa disto. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/101).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar cordenadas para "acertar" o clique aonde você quiser, baseado em referencias que seria o tamanho da tela.

Então tela com `largura X e altura Y.` Meu mouse vai até a cordenada `20x 10y` e clica.

outra maneira seria você usando o tab do teclado. Ai você contaria quantos tabs seriam necessários para chegar no elemento que você quer clicar, e então clicaria e escreveria caso preciso. e por ai vai.

Essas são as duas formas que pensei que você pode utilizar nestes casos. Espero ter ajudado.

Segue exemplo demostrado nesta [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/192610/como-pegar-a-posi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-x-e-y-de-um-elemento-relativo-%C3%A0-tela)

```js
function posicao(e) {
    var el = this;
    var coordenadas = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    var res = 
    console.log('posição x', coordenadas.left, 'posição y', coordenadas.top)
}

document.getElementById('meio').addEventListener('click', posicao);
document.getElementById('fundo').addEventListener('click', posicao);
```

```css
#meio, #fundo {
    background: #ccd;
    padding: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid #500;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#meio {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}

#fundo {
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="meio"></div>
<div id="fundo"></div>
```

Comment: Voce teria algum exemplo disso mano ? Como é mobile não consigo usar com o TAB só por coordenadas...

Comment: tenho um exemplo em javascript

Comment: Obrigado mano, ajudou muito

Comment: poderia votar como util e marcar como a resposta, caso ela seja a resposta?